# Extract data from certain columns and generate new rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe

```
COL1 COL2 COL3        COL4 
 A    B    C    [{COL5: D1, COL6: E1, COL7: F1},
                 {COL5: D2, COL6: E2, COL7: F2},
                 {COL5: D3, COL6: E3, COL7: F3},
                  ...

                 {COL5: D10, COL6: E10, COL7: F10}]
```

The output I want will be:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3  COL5  COL6  COL7
 A    B    C     D1    E1    F1 
 A    B    C     D2    E2    F2
 A    B    C     D3    E3    F3
...
 A    B    C     D10   E10   F10
```

Is there any convenient way I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
data = [{"COL5": f"D{i}", "COL6": f"E{i}", "COL7": f"F{i}"} for i in range(1, 4)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"COL1": ["A"], "COL2": ["B"], "COL3": ["C"], "COL4": [data]})

#   COL1 COL2 COL3                                               COL4
# 0    A    B    C  [{'COL5': 'D1', 'COL6': 'E1', 'COL7': 'F1'}, {...
```

---

`explode` + `join`

```
u = df.explode('COL4').reset_index(drop=True)
u.iloc[:, :-1].join(pd.DataFrame(u['COL4'].tolist()))
```

---

```
  COL1 COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
0    A    B    C   D1   E1   F1
1    A    B    C   D2   E2   F2
2    A    B    C   D3   E3   F3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is elegant :)